# Asana - Rest API - Multipart/form image upload times out

Tags: asana

I am working on a little tool to upload issues found during development to Asana. I am able to get and use post to create tasks etc, but I am unable to do a proper multipart forum upload.

When I run my image upload post request through an independent perl based cgi script I am getting 200's back and an image saved on my server.

When I target Asana, I get 504 gateway timeouts. I am thinking there must be something strict that the perl script is letting through but I have malformed in my request but I am hard pressed to find it.

[image: WireShark http request.]

Is there a web expert or asana expert out there who might be able to help shed some light on what might be missing.

Note the wireshark capture has an extra field. The Asana docs indicate a task field I have tried with and without that field since it is unclear if the task id encoded in the url satisfies that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! 
My boundary= had quotes around the value which was getting through on my cgi / apache setup but not for asana.